# Google API keys need to be different for current Location & Geo coding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I am able to get the current location for the app. But when Geo coding the same LAT/LONG coordinates using the same Google API key gives error.

```
{
"error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API". ...,
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

So my question is can I use the same Google API key for different features like finding the current location, Geocoding etc...

Comment: If I understand correctly, this error message says that Geocoding API is not enabled in your project. You should do both things: enable an API in the project and create an API key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#standard-auth

Comment: @xomena I did enable the key and its working. But my question is can I use one key for multiple google features such as finding places, geocoding etc..

Comment: Depends on restrictions that different APIs support. For example, if you set IP restriction on API key, you can use it with web services (Geocoding, Directions, Distance Matrix), but you cannot use it with Maps JavaScript API, because it supports only HTTP referrer restrictions.